# Following Regex pattern not working in Infopath form validation

Tags: infopath, infopath2010

```
^[^0-9]+$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/BlMmvt6zXgBR1xWw)

**my requirements below**

- Allow only Character like [a-z and A-z]
- Not allow numbers

**Following values not allowed**

Test123

12345Test

1Test12345678

T1E2S3T

1234

**Info path Show Invalid pattern**

[image]

Comment: try `^[^\d]+$` ...I'm not a regex expert but as far as I know `^` refer to next character

Comment: You're going to need to be a bit clearer, do you want to allow ONLY letter characters (`[A-Za-z]`) or are you allowing anything except numeric digits? Your current attempt seems to only disallow digits but would allow all other characters. It might also be worth checking the meaning of the Caret (^) and Dollar ($) for your specific flavour of regex. In some flavors they denote the start and end of a string (which I think is your intent), but might mean something else entirely.

Comment: @Micheled'Amico your answer not working for me

Comment: @Aiken I need anything except numeric digits.

Comment: In which case you need to make that clear in your question, since your requirement "Allow only character like [a-z and A-Z]" is therefore false, as you're allowing non-letter characters so long as they aren't numbers. Out of curiosity though, do you really want me entering `!""^£&$^£%^*()!*"()!*` in your field?

Comment: @Aiken my below answer not allowing any special character.

Answer (score 0):

Following Custom Pattern Work for me.....

```
Field Name | does not match pattern | [a-zA-Z]([ ]*[a-zA-Z])*
```

[image]